# How to mock dependencies for a WebApi 2 controller when using MEF 2 (System.Composition)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mef, bdd, ioc-container

With MEF (System.ComponentModel.Composition) it's possible to add mock objects to the container.

```cs
container.ComposeExportedValue(mock.Object);
```

*ref: [How to use Moq to satisfy a MEF import dependency for unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10223318/444244)*

**How is this possible with the portable MEF libraries (System.Composition)?**

For more context I'll post a bunch of the code I've got so far.

I'm creating [xBehave.net](http://xbehave.github.io/) integration tests over an in-memory [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

I set up the client thus.

```cs
config = new HttpConfiguration();
WebApiConfig.Register(config);
config.DependencyResolver = MefConfig();
server = new HttpServer(config);
Client = new HttpClient(server);
Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
```

I set up my MEF configuration like the default for [WebApiContrib.IoC.Mef](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.IoC.Mef).

```cs
private static IDependencyResolver MefConfig()
{
    var conventions = new ConventionBuilder();
    conventions.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IHttpController>().Export();
    conventions.ForTypesMatching(
        t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.EndsWith(".Parts"))
        .Export()
        .ExportInterfaces();

    var container = new ContainerConfiguration()
        .WithAssemblies(
            new[] { Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ICache)) }, conventions)
        .CreateContainer();

    return new MefDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

Here is the signature of the controller I wish to test. It reads from the cache.

```cs
public MyController(ICache cache) { }
```

Here is the test. The mock is created with [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4).

```cs
[Scenario]
public void RetrieveOnPollingRequest()
{
    const string Tag = "\"tag\"";
    string serverETag = ETag.Create(Tag);

    "Given an If-None-Match header"
        .f(() => Request.Headers.IfNoneMatch.Add(
            new EntityTagHeaderValue(Tag)));
    "And the job has not yet completed"
        .f(() =>
            {
                string tag = serverETag;
                this.MockCache.Setup(x => x.StringGet(tag)).Returns(Tag);
            });
    "When retrieving jobs"
        .f(() =>
            {
                Request.RequestUri = uri;
                Response = Client.SendAsync(Request).Result;
            });
    "Then the status is Not-Modified"
        .f(() =>
            Response.StatusCode.ShouldEqual(HttpStatusCode.NotModified));
}
```

So how do I get that mock into the container instead of the parts that are already exported? Or don't I? Do I need to go and use a different IoC container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the approach taken in the `Microsoft.Composition.Demos.ExtendedPartTypes` sample from the MEF CodePlex site. Below shows registering an instance `mockObject` for the `IAmMocked` service:

```
var container = new ContainerConfiguration()
    .WithExport<IAmMocked>(mockObject)
    .WithAssemblies(
        new[] { Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ICache)) }, conventions)
    .CreateContainer();
```

You'll find the complete code here: http://mef.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#oob/demo/Microsoft.Composition.Demos.ExtendedPartTypes/Program.cs

We intended to get this "into the box" at some point but I don't believe it's happened. Let me know if you have any trouble getting it running!

Comment: That worked a treat, thanks. I can set up one test container with the exported mocks for a test suite and then modify the mock objects depending on the test case.