# MEF Moq-cking on Unit Testing

Tags: .net, wpf, unit-testing, moq, mef

This is the class with the `Import`ed **MEF** attribute

```
public class MyManager : IMyManager {
    [ImportMany]
    public ICollection<Lazy<IContext, IContextMetadata>> Contexts { get; set; }
    public IContext { get; set; }

    // Implemented from IMyManager interface
    public void DoStuff(string name) {
        this.Context = GetContext(name);
    }

    private IContext GetContext(string name) {
        return Contexts.Where(c => c.Metadata.Name.Equals(name)).Single().Value;
    }
}
```

I was following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222654/how-to-use-moq-to-satisfy-a-mef-import-dependency-for-unit-testing) to attempt to mock it and test it but I got lost in the actual/expected values, since in my case I need to assert `MyManager .Context` was changed.

I'm figuring I have to `Mock<IContext>()` and use it to `Assert.Equals`, but how do I mock up the whole lazy list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I typically don't bother mocking an ICollection or IList etc and just use an actual List and similarly for Lazy. I don't think that you gain anything by mocking it out and it ends up being quite hard work with LINQ. Here is an example:

```
Mock<IContext> context = new Mock<IContext>();
Mock<IContextMetadata> contextMetadata = new Mock<IContextMetadata>();
// Do some setup here
ICollection<Lazy<IContext, IContextMetadata>> contexts = new List<Lazy<IContext, IContextMetadata>>();
Lazy<IContext, IContextMetadata> lazyContext = new Lazy<IContext, IContextMetadata>(() => context.Object, contextMetadata.Object);
contexts.Add(lazyContext)
```

Comment: Saved by the Lazy constructor that takes both object and metadata as params